# How can i assign the same yAxis.categories values to series.data in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart where the data that I pass to the **series.data** property exactly match the values that I go to the **categories** property on the y-axis. I tried to put the data in decimal form but then the spline points did not match the various categories.

Categories for me represents a array of times.

This is my chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        reversed: true,
        tickInterval: 1,
        categories: ['0:30', '0:40', '1:00'],
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 0.4, 0.3]
    }]
});
```

What I would like to do is assign the values [0:30 ',' 0:40 ',' 1:00 '] to **series.data** property. But unfortunately you can not assign a string type to **data**.

How can I get around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a decimal value, use index of the specific yAxis category to display value in the right place and modify `tooltip` to display a category value.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8wefsL70/1